# Can I use log transformed dependent variable with GLM (gamma/gaussian log link)?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, lognormal-distribution

My dependent variable is time to an event, recorded in days. The distribution of the dependent variable is right-skewed. T

I have a list of exposure variables that are mostly categorical (binary) and a few continuous variables. Is it wrong to use log-transformed dependent variable with GLM? Should I be using gamma distribution or gaussian with log link? Or would simple linear regression with log-transformed dependent variable suffice? I am hoping to run a log-normal regression.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are investigating time to event, you need to consider survival analysis, not linear regressions. Thy to look up cox regression

Comment: Are all event times observed? If so, what you discuss could work (distribution may of course not fit well). If some records did not have an event during the observation time, you'd need survival analysis methods.

Comment: Thanks Kirsten and Björn! The time to event was constructed by asking participants to recall the date of onset of symptoms occurrence to the time of diagnosis. We collected data from the participants after they have been diagnosed with the disease. We opined that constituted a retrospective cohort study. I have done Cox regression but there's a suggestion to look into log normal regression